# finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x) & 2\cos(x)\sin(x) \\ 2\cos(x)\sin(x) & \sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)\end{bmatrix}$$

1. Given the matrix, determine the eigenvalues of of $A$.
2. With $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, for each eigenvalue from part (1), determine the eignvectors $x_1$ and $x_2$

when it comes to $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$, I am pretty unsure of how i should go about doing or approach this question. Would really appreciate if someone could give me some help :)

Comment: i got characteristic polynomial is (λ−sin2(x)−cos2(x))(λ-sin2(x)+cos2(x)) and i think i am wrong

Comment: sorry , i got this (λ−sin(x)^2−cos(x)^2)(λ-sin(x)^2+cos(x)^2)

Answer (score 0):

From $$\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$$ and $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(2x) & \sin(2x) \\ \sin(2x) & -\cos(2x) \end{bmatrix}$$

$$A-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(2x)-\lambda & \sin(2x) \\ \sin(2x) & -\cos(2x)-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I)&=(-\lambda+\cos(2x))(-\lambda-\cos(2x))-\sin^2(2x)\\&=\lambda^2-\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)\\&=\lambda^2-1
\end{align}

Can you solve for the eigenvalues and solve the rest?

Once you substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ into the expression of $A$, you have converted the problem to a usual solve for eigenvalue and eigenvector problem.

Comment: Hi , yes i am able to solve the rest of the question :) thanks so much for the help! really appreciate.